# codename one how to add a badge to the sideMenu Icon in toolbar

Tags: codenameone

how can I add a budge to that SideMenu Icon

[image: menu icon]

```
mainToolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(avatarBox);

    mainToolbar.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu(" Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e -> {
        ManagementDashboard mdas = new ManagementDashboard(this);
        mdas.Home();
    });
```

Comment: Define the theme constant: `hideLeftSideMenuBool=true`. This will hide the menu entirely. You can then use the answer below to add your own menu button which just invokes the Toolbars open side drawer API

Comment: Thank you Shai Almog, I have managed to customized the toolbar and added my icons ,  How do I set the Action of my menu icon to open the Side drawer

Comment: `form.getToolbar().openSideMenu()`

Comment: Thank you Shai, it all worked well only that the drawer has lost its two features,1: the setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds; 2: set Blur background. those two are not working

Comment: How did you implement these two features? Did you make any special settings?

Comment: notifiations.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                mainToolbar.openSideMenu();
            }
        });#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true; 
    scrollVisibleBool: false;
    hideLeftSideMenuBool:true;
} thtas thee action of the icon and then

Comment: The behavior of that API is identical to the one we invoke internally. Are you using the on-top mode? (It's the default): https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/14cd2c13740c2c3fc46b5cdb33b1c619f03a6b34/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.java#L341-L347

This is how the builtin button shows the menu: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/14cd2c13740c2c3fc46b5cdb33b1c619f03a6b34/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.java#L1435-L1443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions is a bit vague and I am not sure that i understand what you are asking, but in my experience, the only way to customize the toolbar to do anything beyond what the out-of-the-box toolbars methods offer is to use `setTitleComponent` and add your own custom container to your toolbar. The downside of this is that you will have to redesing a lot of your toolbars as you will be basically creating them again from scratch. You can center a new container with `setTitleComponent`, override its `calcPreferredSize` to stretch it across the entire toolbar horizontally, and stick stuff in it as you would in any Container (use any Layout, etc)

Another way of achieving your goal would be to extend the Toolbar class and manually change things within it. But the Toolbar class is quite heavy and you might spend much more time trying to figure out what to change than by using the first method

Method #1 sample code:

```
//stick stuff in this container to create your own toolbar
Container titleContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout()) {
        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            Dimension original = super.calcPreferredSize();
            return new Dimension(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), original.getHeight());
        }
    };
form.getToolbar().setTitleComponent(titleContainer);
```

Here is an example of what could be achieved if you go this route (pretty much anything):

[image]